# run a project before main project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, build

I have a project that I use to convert an input text file to css.
I want to run this project every time I run my MVC project so it generates the newest css file.

I know that I can run a Task in BeforeBuild to achieve this, but it requires that I link to the dll file for my project. (This is a problem because if I use a dll file, then I would have to manually update the dll file

Is there a way I can build and run my first project, then launch MVC?

Comment: Can you add a dependency on the first project to the second?  At that point, you should be able to safely say the project has been built...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the MVC project in the solution and select `Project Dependencies`, then check the project that you want to be built first

[image]

That will make sure that the dependency project builds first.

Then right click on Solution, select Properties and select Multiple startup projects in order to run two projects

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works. I try to avoid it because the first project is merely a tool. Ideally I would prefer the project runs before build.. (which I think it's kinda impossible)